# Could improper installation of a weather vane on the roof cause a collapse?

Tags: roof

[image]
My daughter thinks  that becsuse of,the way this was installed the roof is no longer safe and will collapse. Has the integtity of this building been compromised?

Comment: A lot more information is needed, what specifically could have damaged the roof, how? Can you attach a close up picture? Please elaborate on the issue.

Comment: She  thinks we need sn engineer  to to look at it

Comment: I don't see an issue if you mean holes for the screws so they didn't split the wood. Unless you drilled such huge holes that the beam is literal swiss cheese but this depends on the beam size, how it is supported, etc.

Comment: Im nor sure how its supported . Its just a typical  shed/ barn. It passed inspection when we bought the property 2 years ago.  Im sure its not swiss cheese. Weathervsnes  are installed all the time . She thinks the whole barn will collapse  and wants yo replace whole barn.

Comment: No one here will be able to give you an answer as somebody who could see this in person. If you want to know for sure, you need somebody on site to inspect this. That being said, this is a very small weather vane on a tiny building, where small screws were probably used for installation.

Answer (score 3):

Someone is being very paranoid!!! There's ABSOLUTELY no way the structural integrity of the roof has been compromised by installing a weather vane.

Edit:
Something else to consider about your daughters worries about the structural stability of the roof... Someone had to physically get on that roof to install your weather vane. If the roof was unstable, there wouldn't be a weather vane there as the roof would've collapsed under the weight of the person that installed it.

Comment: I could see moisture being a problem if the holes aren't sealed well.  As long as water isn't getting in, it's fine.

Comment: I don't know what happened to the OPs previous comment, but she stated that whoever installed it drilled holes for the screws and then caulked them...

Comment: Sounds like a good install the caulking prevents water from getting in I agree there is no way this could compromise the entire structure.+